# Can I use DDR3 1600 SODIMM's in a DDR3 1333 laptop (2011 macbook pro)?

Tags: laptop, memory, macbook-pro

I'd like to do this because DDR3-1333mhz memory is out of stock in the shops where I live, but they have plenty of 1600mhz memory.

Normally this kind of thing is OK, but I noticed that DDR3-1600 SODIMMs say they're rated for 1.35 volts, whereas DDR3-1333 ones say they're rated for 1.5 volts.

Does this voltage labeling matter?

I'm looking at replacing the laptop's RAM entirely so there won't be a mix of old/new RAM.

Specifically, I want to put two of these:
https://www.pbtech.co.nz/product/MEMKIN64099/Kingston-Laptop-4GB-1600MHz-DDR3L-Non-ECC-CL11-SOD

Into one of these:
https://support.apple.com/kb/sp645?locale=en_US

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Crucial site does recommend the same low voltage memory (http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/macbook-pro-%2813-inch%2C-late-2011%29/CT3373722) through their model selector. Up to you if you want to go with either brand.